# When making a youtube video of coding tutorial, is it good to have the keyboard sounds while I'm typing?

Tags: youtube, programming, tutorial

I'm making a youtube tutorial on programming. But I'm unsure if I should keep the keyboard sound on the video or record on without it.

Does the keyboard sound, even when the sound is very low, it's good? Bad? Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 2):

I presume you generally talk while typing, right? Well, when I need to focus on a human voice, any distracting sound is unwelcome. This includes keyboard typing. I do not see any benefit of such sounds when making tutorials during parts when you talk. Also, keep in mind that people with hearing aids will benefit much from a clean voice with no other sounds.

When you have scenes in the video where there is nothing to talk about but you have to type a lot, the silence might be a bit irritating. However, you could cut the boring part and skip ahead until we see the complete code block. Alternatively speed up the scene.